# Default password in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to configure a default password because in the project I am working on, It is the admin who is to create accounts for users.

Of course, if a put a default value on my model, It will not hash the password. How else can I approach this

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('POBox');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand 100%. I see you have a `role_id` so why not use the built in Auth in Laravel and set your admin section to only allow users with the `role_id` of 1 to access that section. Set a default of 0 for everyone else.

Comment: I have multiple users 4 in total so role id goes from 0 to 3. And I want only my Admin register the other users so I need a default password

Comment: Create a Roles table and give your admin the role_id of 5. Then use a Route Group to protect your admin pages.
`///////ADMIN PROTECTED
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','roles'], 'roles' => 'Admin'], function () {
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
});`

Comment: I have already done that. For my system to make sense, the admin is not supposed to create passwords for users. I would like him to only be able to create accounts for them and set a default password that can be changed by a user. Do you get me now?

Answer (score 0):

Have the Admin only create the user and then email the New user a password reset.

**Form:**

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.user.store') }}" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="first_name" class="no-pad-left col-form-label white-txt muli w4">First Name</label>
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="last_name" class="no-pad-left col-form-label white-txt muli w4">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="email" class="no-pad-left col-form-label white-txt muli w4">E-Mail Address</label>
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <button type="submit" class="bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-700 text-navy-500 md:w-1/4 sm:w-full w-full font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline shadow-lg" type="button">
                    Create User
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function adminUserStore(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'first_name'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);

        $quickpass = substr( str_shuffle( str_repeat( 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10 ) ), 0, 10 );
        $adminName = Auth::user()->first_name.' '.Auth::user()->last_name; 
        $newuser = User::create([
            'first_name'=> $request->first_name,
            'last_name'=> $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($quickpass),
            'role_id' => '0',
            'added_by' => $adminName,
        ]);
        Mail::to($newuser->email)
        ->send(new NewUserPassReset(
            $request->input('first_name'),
            $request->input('last_name'),
            $request->input('email')
          ));

        return back()->with('success','The user has been created and a password reset email has been sent to them.');     

    }
```

You should be able to figure out the email part. Then in the email that is sent to the new user, include a link to the Reset Password route.

That's how I do it.

Comment: So this is how my controller must look like?

Comment: @Jimmyjbk Here is the form and controller. This should get you 85% of the way there.

Comment: It's the standard Laravel Password Reset link that you email to the New User. We already created them an account so they only need to enter there email to reset the password. `www.example.com/password/reset`

Comment: As I can see, You used NewUserPassReset. Is it pre implemented in laravel?

Comment: Yeah man. Its created when you do the php artisan make:auth and do your first migration. Not sure how you missed this.

Comment: The problem is that I don't find it anywhere in my project

Answer (score -1):

You can use default values in a Model.

**User.php**

```
public class User extends Model
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(40))
    ];
}
```

Str::random will give you a random 40-chars String. You can change this to anything you like. 
Hash::make() will hash the String so Laravel can check the Hash when User tries to login.